# zabbix Standard items vfs.file.exists

Tags: zabbix

mysql backup file will create at 23:35，

**scripts:**

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump -uroot -padmin  mysql > /data/backup/mysql-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).sql
```

the struct of the file is `mysql-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).sql`.

**backup file:**

```
[root@zabbix-agent ~]# cd /data/backup/
[root@zabbix-agent backup]# ll
总用量 3072000
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1048576000 5月  15 23:35 mysql-2018-05-29.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1048576000 5月  17 23:35 mysql-2018-05-30.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1048576000 5月  16 23:35 mysql-2018-05-31.sql
```

I want to check file by inside key `vfs.file.exists` at 00:01 everyday.

**zabbix items:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVg45.jpg)

**key:**
`vfs.file.exists[/data/$(date -d "yesterday" +%Y-%m-%d).sql]`

but the zabbix works fail,I want to know how can I use the `vfs.file.exists` to check the backup file.

Comment: It is reasonable to send backup status using zabbix_sender (or maybe package/library for programming language that backup software was written in) from backup software itself: if backup was succeded, you may send "0", if it fails - you can send some error_code (say, "187"). vfs.file.exists cant do what you want: you cant insert bash output as file name for this key, zabbix simply use first parameter of vfs.file.exists key as a path specification, but i'm sure you dont have any files named "/data/$(date -d "yesterday" +%Y-%m-%d).sql" :)

Comment: I got it,zabbix_sender is a nice choice.

Answer (score 1):

In Zabbix 3.0 the [scheduling intervals](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/items/item/custom_intervals#scheduling_intervals) were added where you can define exactly at what time the execution of the check should be performed. In your case the scheduling interval instruction would be

`h0m1`

which stands for "every day at 0 hours 1 minute".